# System-wide dynamic library functions hooking on macos

Tags: c++, c, macos

I'm working on on-line encryption driver for MacOS. And one of the issues I encountered recently is that I have to control(hook/intercept) some of the regular system functions (on application/user level) like : mmap, open, close ... on system-wide basis, so that I could arbitrary turn on or off that control.
I looked at some of the examples and solutions available, - probably not all of them, - but they all work for that very application that does the hooking, while I need the sort hook that could intercept system calls made from any other application. For example, what do I do to hook and control the call to, say, 'mmap' in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib, regardless of what application calls that 'mmap'.

I tried rd_route, substitue ... but they seem to work for the application itself and other applications bypass the hook.

Comment: You should read papers how rootkits achieve that. That will heavily depend on MacOS version.

Comment: You’ll probably need to develop a kernel extension to do this but for a partial userspace solution, check out `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` (which is macOS’ `LD_PRELOAD` equivalent).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you confirmed my doubts ... I looked again at other approaches and see that it must be kext. Instead of dealing with numerous dylibs one has to work with syscall table in kernel.